# create json structure from php and mysql

Tags: php, json

I want to generate `Json` from PHP and produce results like below

```
series: [{
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
        }, {
            name: "Chrome",
            y: 24.03,
            drilldown: "Chrome"
        }, {
            name: "Firefox",
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: "Firefox"
        }, {
            name: "Safari",
            y: 4.77,
            drilldown: "Safari"
        }, {
            name: "Opera",
            y: 0.91,
            drilldown: "Opera"
        }, {
            name: "Proprietary or Undetectable",
            y: 0.2,
            drilldown: null
        }]
    }]
```

how to create the result structure like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_array()` function for retrieving values as array from mysql database using a while loop and `json_encode()` the result array.
Example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $result[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that contains array of object and then those contains some properties that will produce something as you want `name:"Brands"` and `colorByPoint: true`. Besides those properties the object also contains another array of object. Those objects in array will contains properties like `name: "Safari"`, `y: 4.77` etc. Then use `encode_json($CreatedVariable)` method to produce the JSON you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode(); Function
this would help you.
Use like this

```
echo json_encode(array('series'=>$array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your PHP data, you can use the  [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) function. PHP json_encode() function is used for encoding JSON in PHP. This function returns the JSON representation of a value on success or FALSE on failure.

Below is the example that illustrates how to use `json_encode` function

```
  $catId = $_GET['catId'];
  $catId = $_POST['catId'];   

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","DBName");
if(!$conn)
{
    trigger_error('Could not Connect' .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$array = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $row;
}

echo'{"ProductsData":'.json_encode($array).'}'; //Here ProductsData is just a simple String u can write anything instead
mysqli_close('$conn');
```